# How can I fix sfdx error: "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined"

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm getting an error similar to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/251815/51499) and I've checked to see if I could resolve it in the same way, but it appears to be a different issue.

Whenever I try to push, deploy or convert to metadata, I'm getting the error

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

This error also shows up in the Problems tab in VS Code, but clicking on it gives me another error (Unable to open "": File is a directory.)

[image]

This issue was reported on the [github/cli forum](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/94#issuecomment-519593942) by others over the last 8-9 months, but there's no clear resolution. I've added more detail (json error output) there.

The only "path" argument I can find is in the sfdx-project.json, and it's clearly a string:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [{ "path": "force-app", "default": true }],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "46.0"
}
```

I'm completely stuck with no clear way to debug this. Would appreciate any ideas...

Comment: Did you try creating a new scratch org to target?

Comment: It won't let me even convert to mdapi where no org is involved. Something is internally off with the source.

Comment: I'm thinking the error message is just wrong, and there may be an errant remnant from the merge conflict resolution. I'm currently searching for things like `<<<<< HEAD` etc. Also combing through the .forceignore file.

Comment: Very helpful answer to similar issue ([link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/273101/132698))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**FIXED IT!**
I found that I could do a `sfdx force:source:deploy -p [filepath]` on individual files and on directories. So, I started at the top and worked my way down.

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default` = same error

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/applications` = success

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/appMenus` = success

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/aura` = success

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/classes` = success

...etc., until
`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/staticResources` = SAME ERROR

So I stepped into that directory and discovered a meta file for a graphic (png) that was missing. I pulled the png from my other files (not in the project), added it to the directory, then did...

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/staticresources` = SUCCESS

So then, I tried `sfdx force:source:push` and SUCCESS!

WHAT HAVE WE LEARNED?

1. That error message is not at all helpful and appears to occur when there's a variety of errors in the package you're trying to push.
2. If you can still use deploy (I could), start at the top and work your way down until you can isolate the directory/file where the error originates.

Comment: Very helpful! I had the exact same issue and this approach helped me diagnose it.

Comment: I had the same error after I accidentally copied a "Object" folder into the parent directory. Additional help for anybody debugging this: delete the scratch cache in `.sfdx/orgs/username@example.com` after you fixed the folder structure.

Comment: Do you have to use " these " or nah ? Or these ' ' you didn't use them I tried all three and none worked.

Comment: I just used the cli with no single or double quotes. The only quotes in this post are about the path file, which ended up not being significant. No changes to that.

Comment: For us, the inclusion of object translations cause sfdx to choke and throw this error. We had to remove them and reset everything in ~/.sfdx/

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you put an object definition into a folder that SFDX doesn't recognize. For example, this happened to me when i put a Custom Metadata definition in a folder labelled 'customMetadata' (it expected a folder called 'objects', apparently).

Comment: This is documented somewhat on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm but that doesn't change the fact that people sometimes make mistakes and better error messages would really not be expecting too much from a company the size of Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, There must be an invalid static resource.
Please verify your static resource files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was related to copy & paste file, when vsc added " copy" to the file name.
Agree that error message should be better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have package xml built with all the files.
I tried several changes like deleting all the files from project and retrieving them again. Not sure what exactly worked, but it worked after I restarted closed and reopened vscode