# Can't push cause of this error

Tags: lightning-web-components

I keep getting this error when I try to push:
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined.

Comment: What’s the path parameter you are imputing ? Also what command you are using ?

Comment: sfdx force:source:push -u OhiScratchTwo

Comment: Which operating system and cli version ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix sfdx error: "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272976/how-can-i-fix-sfdx-error-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-receive)

Comment: I am using Macos. Where do I check my cli version?

Comment: find the version using sfdx --version. Note that we also need to know little about what metadata you re pushing to guide you through the cause of the error.

Comment: sfdx-cli/7.58.2-937f666ed4 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: This is what is in my package.xml