# Getting the error : The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

When I am trying to push an lwc component to the org using `SFDX: Deploy This Source To Org` I am getting the following error :

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
```

It was working fine and suddenly it started getting this error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I went through this link but it did not help : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272976/how-can-i-fix-sfdx-error-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-receive

Comment: Please [edit] to add more detail, such as (implied but not stated) you are using VSCode with the SF CLI plugin, what file(s) you had open and/or selected, if any, how you had created the LWC you are trying to deploy, whether it has all the necessary files (including the -meta.xml ones) and other information you might find helpful if **YOU** were trying to solve someone's issue.

Comment: Also, did you check [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/288942/50252) to verify if you have some files in the wrong place? (This is where sharing the folder structure in your question would help. Add more detail via [edit].)